# Linq expression get first two elements SUM

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
var ab = hazirlikOgrenciBilgileri.Select(s => s.Notlar.Sum(x => x.AgirlikliNot)).Take(2);
```

This is my code: `hazirlikOgrenciBilgileri` has 3 elements.And 3 elements all of them have "Notlar" AND "AgirlikliNot" has 8 value .

How can I get for  the firs two elements of hazirlikOgrenciBilgileri SUM agirlikliNot?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here, your code seems to do what you describe.  Try to provide a [mcve] showing your inputs, explain what your current output is and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var ab = hazirlikOgrenciBilgileri.Take(2).Select(s => s.Notlar.Sum(x => x.AgirlikliNot));

Comment: This will give the same result, surely?  If there's a problem with the code in the question, this code has the same problem.